# Refresh error Power BI service, exception was raised by IDataReader

Tags: powerbi, gateway

During my first refresh of my PowerBI dataset the following error was raised:
The operation is timed out.. The exception was raised by the IDataReader interface. Please review the error message and provider documentation for further information and corrective action. Table: Grootboekmutaties BV (budgetten).

I first connected to a local SQL database where the backup is just two weeks old, there I could load the data and everything worked fine. But when I publish and connect via a gateway and data connection, I got the error above.

I tested the gateway and data connection on another table, and that worked fine.

Comment: Have a look at: https://rohitvangala.wordpress.com/2017/02/02/error-the-exception-was-raised-by-idatareader-interface/